# How to trigger IReactiveDerivedList reset from changes in source IReactiveList?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am using Reactive Extensions to create an `IReactiveDerivedList<IAmSelectable>` (selectedItems) from a source `ReactiveList<IAmSelectable>` (items):

```
selectedItems = items.CreateDerivedCollection(
    c => c,
    null,
    c => c.IsSelected,
    null,
    items.Changed.Select(_ => items.Select(c => c.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsSelected)).Merge()).Select(c => c).Switch());
```

where:

```
public interface IAmSelectable
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to trigger a reset of `selectedItems` when the selection state of any `IAmSelectable` in `items` changes.  When I attempt to do so, however, I get an `InvalidOperationException` stating "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."  What's the right approach to do this?

**EDIT:** The following approach also produces the same exceptions:

```
items.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
selectedItems = items.CreateDerivedCollection(
    c => c,
    null,
    c => c.IsSelected,
    null,
    items.ItemChanged.Where(c => c.PropertyName == "IsSelected"));
```

Comment: I can't replicate this.  Is there anything else you're doing that might cause it?  As ever, a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: The exception occurs intermittently in my live code, where there's a lot of other things going on (derived lists of derived list, etc); it could possibly be something else, but the issue goes away when I comment out this code.  I did try to replicate the issue in a unit test but was also unable to do so.  If I can figure out a way to systematically reproduce the error with some example code, I'll definitely post it here.  In the interim, sorry for not providing a more meaningful question.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles Mager suggested, there was something else I was doing that caused the issue.  The following line, in the constructor with the code above, was  the cause of the exception:

```
service.Items.ItemsAdded.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).Subscribe(vm => SelectedItem = vm);
```

I'm not sure why, but the issue went away when I changed it to:

```
service.Items.ItemsAdded.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Immediate).Subscribe(vm => SelectedItem = vm);
```

I've found when dealing with derived reactive lists that collection modified exceptions can be difficult to debug, especially when there's nothing in the call stack, thread list, or intellitrace that relates to anything in my code except the entry method.  Moreover, apparent problems with the reactive derived list are more often than not a red herring - I encountered this a number of times by systematically eliminating calls to `CreateDerivedList` until the exception went away, only to find the problem somewhere else.

The basic lessons I've learned in debugging this problem are these:

- If you're using a foreach loop inside a call to subscribe, make sure you've called `ToList()` on the collection to be enumerated.  (This is stated repeatedly throughout Stack Overflow.)
- If you've got any select statements that might interact with the reactive lists, try calling `ToList()` there as well.
- Look out for potential timing issues; use of different schedulers sometimes helps, as in the case above.

Hope these pointers help someone else spend less time on this sort of problem than I did here.